# Retrive all values from listscompare and modify them

Tags: c#, list, methods

I'm locked to show list member, compare and modify members.
This program is a automotive shop and I got Vendors (Salesman) , Customers (same method of vendors) and I will have and interface for cars/cargo/etc...

for now in' concentrating to methods for this list :

```
public static List<Venditori> Venditori = new List<Venditori>();
```

These are the proprieties of Vendors:

```
public class Venditori
{

    public Guid Id { set; get; }
    public string NomeVenditore { get; set; }
    public string CognomeVenditore { get; set; }
    public string TelefonoVenditore { get; set; }
    public string EmailVenditore { get; set; }
    public bool VenditoreAttivo { get; set; }
    public string DateTime { get; set;  }



    public Venditori(Guid id, string nomevenditore, string cognomevenditore, string telefonovenditore,
                     string emailvenditore, bool venditoreattivo, string datetime)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.NomeVenditore = nomevenditore;
        this.CognomeVenditore = cognomevenditore;
        this.TelefonoVenditore = telefonovenditore;
        // Without this.
        EmailVenditore = emailvenditore;
        VenditoreAttivo = venditoreattivo;
        DateTime = datetime;

        venditoreattivo = true;

    }
```

}

This is  method to insert values, also print what i've just insert into list :

```
public static Venditori Registravenditore()
    {


        Venditori v = new Venditori();
        v.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("- Inserisci il Nome del Venditore : -");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");


        v.NomeVenditore = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Clear();


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("- Inserisci il Cognome del Venditore : -");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");


        v.CognomeVenditore = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Clear();


        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("- Inserisci il Telefono del Venditore : -");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

        v.TelefonoVenditore = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("- Inserisci la Mail del Venditore : -");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");

        v.EmailVenditore = Console.ReadLine();

        v.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        Liste.Venditori.Add(v);

        Console.Clear();



        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Hai inserito il venditore {v.NomeVenditore} - {v.CognomeVenditore} - Avente GuId - {v.Id} - ");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Il telefono è : {v.TelefonoVenditore} - La sua mail è : {v.EmailVenditore}");
        Console.WriteLine($"- Il Venditore è attivo dal : {v.DateTime}");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("");




        return v;


    }
```

The problem are 
Problem1 : When I start the method to list ( ElencoVenditori() ) all Vendors and relative proprieties, return to me only the last insert. I've tried to use Liste.Venditori.FindAll() but need to insert some paramether in FindAll and I don't know what I have to pass. Searched everywhere in web, first in Microsoft.Docs, but nothing ...
This is the code :

```
 public static List<Venditori> ElencoVenditori()
    {
        // Eseguo un ForEach per ciclare dalla lista i miei dati. A differenza del While che cicla un condizionale
        // e For che cicla una index, questo comando è dedicato alle liste.
        // Associa alla variabile "item", tramite il comando "in", la lista venditori e mostra in console cosa contengono

        foreach (var item in Liste.Venditori)
        {

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine($"I Venditori presenti in Lista sono :  Nome - {item.NomeVenditore} | GuId - {item.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"                                      Telefono - {item.TelefonoVenditore} | Mail - {item.EmailVenditore}");
            Console.WriteLine($"                                      Venditore Aggiunto il -  {item.DateTime}");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

        }

        return Liste.Venditori;



    }
```

Problem 2 
I got another method ( VerificaListaVenditori() ), that should show me if one "Venditore" is present or not in the list, using as search index the name (NomeVenditore) or the surname (CognomeVenditore). 
At the search using any index,  i retrive and exception error:

---

```
Unhandled Exception: System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
   at VenditaAutoConcessionarioConsole.Methods.VendorsMethods.VerificaListaVenditori() in C:\Users\Faggiano\source\repos\Progetti\ConcessionarioAuto\ConcessionarioAutoConsole\VenditaAutoConcessionarioConsole\Methods\VendorsMethods.cs:line 168
   at VenditaAutoConcessionarioConsole.Methods.ProgramMethods.VendorSelect() in C:\Users\Faggiano\source\repos\Progetti\ConcessionarioAuto\ConcessionarioAutoConsole\VenditaAutoConcessionarioConsole\Methods\ProgramMethods.cs:line 70
   at VenditaAutoConcessionarioConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Faggiano\source\repos\Progetti\ConcessionarioAuto\ConcessionarioAutoConsole\VenditaAutoConcessionarioConsole\Program.cs:line 53
Premere un tasto per continuare . . .
```

---

This is  the code :

```
public static void VerificaListaVenditori()
    {

        string nomevenditore = "";
        string cognomevenditore = "";

        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("- Inserisci il Nome od il Cognome del Venditore per la ricerca -");
        Console.WriteLine("-------------- (Restituisce le Proprietà) ----------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();

        nomevenditore = Console.ReadLine();
        cognomevenditore = Console.ReadLine();


        string risultatoPositivo = "Il Venditore {0} è presente - Avente GuId {1} - " +
            "                       Il Cognome è {2} - Il Telefono è {3} - La Mail è {4}" +
            "                       E' attivo dal {5}";
        string risultatoNegativoNome = $"Il Venditore ''{nomevenditore}'' non è presente nella Lista";
        string risultatoNegativoCognome = $"Il Venditore ''{cognomevenditore}'' non è presente nella Lista ";



        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < Liste.Venditori.Count; i++)
        {


            if (nomevenditore == Liste.Venditori[i].NomeVenditore | cognomevenditore == Liste.Venditori[i].CognomeVenditore)
            {
                index = i;
                //// Visualizza risultatoPositivo ed interrompe il ciclo
                //Console.WriteLine(risultatoPositivo); 
            }

        }



        if (index >= 0)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(risultatoPositivo, Liste.Venditori[index].NomeVenditore, Liste.Venditori[index].Id, Liste.Venditori[index].CognomeVenditore, Liste.Venditori[index].TelefonoVenditore, Liste.Venditori[index].EmailVenditore));
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(risultatoNegativoNome, risultatoNegativoCognome);
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------");
        }



    }
```

The full code can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/maurofasciano/ConcessionarioAutoConsole).

Answer (score 0):

If the `List.Venditori` is accessed through the index then it must be 0 to `List.Venditori.Count-1`.

So your for loop must be

```
for (int i = 0; i < Liste.Venditori.Count; i++)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, are you talking about the exception error, right ?